# Accessing enclosing Python environment from QGIS processing qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator algorithm

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, field-calculator, qgis-processing

Instead of iterating over all features in a layer I thought I'd make use of the advanced field calculator in the hope of achieving better performance and less code. The code is part of a sequence of algoritms and depends on two layers (`grid['OUTPUT']` and `input`), like so:

```
layer = context.getMapLayer(input)

cell_values = processing.run('qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator',
            {
                'INPUT': grid['OUTPUT'],
                'FIELD_NAME': 'cellval',
                'FIELD_TYPE': 0, # Float
                'GLOBAL': 'from qgis.core import QgsGeometry; layer = ???',
                'FORMULA': '''
input_geoms=QgsGeometry.polygonize([f.geometry() for f in layer.getFeatures()])
value = $geom.intersection(input_geoms).area()/$geom.area()
                ''',
                'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
            },
            is_child_algorithm=True,
            context=context,
            feedback=feedback)
```

When running this algoritm interactively in QGIS I can access the input layer from the project:
`layer=QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('input')`, and when using processing one can usually get it from the context: `layer = context.getMapLayer(input)`. But how can I access this context in the GLOBAL parameter above (the question marks)?